# Using ruby 2.6.6 on rails 5.2.3. Will this cause any problems? downgrade ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have downloaded rails 5.2.3 but I am using ruby 2.6.6. I know rails 5.2 works with versions <2.7. But I saw some people said that using 2.7 ruby on 5.2 rails can cause problems. I just want to know if 2.6.6 can also cause problems as ruby >2.5 works for rails 6.

If I need to downgrade ruby please let me know how to do it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't fret about problems you don't have. Rails 6 and Ruby 2.7 are completely fine, as are Rails 5.2 and Ruby 2.6.

I'm not aware of any serious incompatibilities between Ruby 2.6 and Ruby 2.7, it's a fairly harmless upgrade. The last major friction point was from Ruby 2.3 to Ruby 2.4 where changes to certain internals made some very old, no longer maintained gems fail to compile correctly. The impact on modern code-bases was relatively minimal.

*If*, and this is a big if, you have problems please articulate them with a specific example and we can work through solving them. It's rare, but not entirely improbable, that downgrading solves the issue, but most of the time upgrading is the correct path.

Generally you should be using the latest version of both Rails and Ruby in conjunction. This means that if your application is not maintained as well as you'd like you're more future-proofed than if you'd deliberately picked an older version of either. Remember, Ruby versions do fall out of their [maintenance window](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/branches/) eventually, as does Rails. Ruby 2.5 support ends on March 31, 2021, and Ruby 2.4 has already hit end-of-life.

Using 2.7 instead of 2.6 buys you another couple of years of support you would not otherwise have.